# Simplify Ruby Statement

Tags: ruby

I have a long codes here w/c is a combination of both begin-end block and an if statement. How can I simplify this in an all if statement?

```
print "Put a number between 0 to 100: "

begin
numb = gets.chomp
numb = Integer(numb)
rescue 
    print "Please put a number not a text: "
    retry
end

if numb < 0
  puts "You can't enter a negative number!"
elsif numb <= 50
  puts "#{numb} is between 0 and 50"
elsif numb <= 100
  puts "#{numb} is between 51 and 100"
else
  puts "#{numb} is above 100"
end
```

REFACTORING

Comment: I don't see anything else you can do here, maybe try `case` instead?, But, it would be looking same as `if else` in terms of number of lines.

Comment: The `retry` turns your `begin/end` block into a loop. This is quite different from the way your `if` / `elsif` expressions work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code review and improvement requests might better suit http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice to specify the exception class that you want to rescue. In that case, it is an ArgumentError.

Besides, your code looks ok.
Reading input could be abstracted to a method:

```
def read_input
  Integer(gets.chomp)
rescue ArgumentError
  print "Please put a number not a text: "
  retry
end
```

In the second part of your code, only thing is that `puts` could be moved in front of `if` to avoid typing `puts` in every case.

```
print "Put a number between 0 to 100: "
numb = read_input
puts if numb < 0
  "You can't enter a negative number!"
elsif numb <= 50
  "#{numb} is between 0 and 50"
elsif numb <= 100
  "#{numb} is between 51 and 100"
else
  "#{numb} is above 100"
end
```

That part of code could also be expressed by ranges and `case` statements, which is arguably more readable:

```
puts case numb
  when -Float::INFINITY...0 then "You can't enter a negative number!"
  when 0..50 then "#{numb} is between 0 and 50"
  when 51..100 then "#{numb} is between 51 and 100"
  else "#{numb} is above 100"
end
```

Furthermore, the `-Float::INFINITY...0` statement could be expressed by `proc(&:negative?)`. `Numeric#positive?` and `Numeric#negative?` methods are available in Ruby sice 2.3 version.

Comment: You should keep `retry` instead of calling `read_input` recursively.

Comment: Could you explain why? Is it because of the readability, best practices, performance, or maybe something else?

Comment: Ruby does not recognize tail-recursive calls. Each call is therefore pushed to the call stack. You can see this by entering several invalid numbers and then hitting Control-C (which should end the program and display the current backtrace). Now, try that again with `retry` and compare the backtraces.

Comment: True. Thank's for pointing that out. Corrected.

Comment: You could also use `when proc(&:negative?)` instead of `when -Float::INFINITY...0`.

Comment: Thx! I also added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
print 'Put a number between 0 to 100: '

begin
  numb = Integer(gets.chomp)
rescue ArgumentError
  print 'Please put a number not a text:'
  retry
end

case numb
when -Float::INFINITY...0
  'You can\'t enter a negative number!'
when 0..50
  "#{numb} is between 0 and 50"
when 51..100
  "#{numb} is between 51 and 100"
else
  "#{numb} is above 100"
end
```

Youl [shouldn't rescue Exception](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-exception-vs-standarderror-whats-the-difference/)

According with ruby [code style](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#strings) you can change unnecessary doubled quotes. (take a look to [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) gem)

and change if else then by when.

Comment: Although your last point is correct, the OP did not rescue `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use a case statement or if there is too much cases you implement the check on your own based on a variable storing the limits to check the integer against.

The below code does three times the same thing with your initial code, a case statement and an array storing the limits, up to you to get the most appropriate solution.

```
(1..7).each {
  print "Put a number between 0 to 100: "

  begin
    numb = gets.chomp
    numb = Integer(numb)
  rescue
    print "Please put a number not a text: "
    retry
  end

  if numb < 0
      puts "You can't enter a negative number!"
  elsif numb <= 50
      puts "#{numb} is between 0 and 50"
  elsif numb <= 100
      puts "#{numb} is between 51 and 100"
  else
      puts "#{numb} is above 100"
  end

  case
    when numb < 0
      puts "[case] You can't enter a negative number!"
    when numb.between?(0, 50)
      puts "[case] #{numb} is between 0 and 50"
    when numb.between?(51, 100)
      puts "[case] #{numb} is between 51 and 100"
    when numb > 100
      puts "[case] #{numb} is above 100"
  end

  lim = [100, 0, 50].sort
  if (numb < lim.first)
    puts "[limit list] You can't enter a negative number!"
  elsif (numb > lim.last)
      puts "[limit list] #{numb} is above #{lim.last}"
  else
    (lim.first lim.size - 1).each_index { |i|
      min_value = lim[i].eql?(0) ? 0 : lim[i]+1
      if numb.between?(min_value,lim[i+1])
        puts "[limit list] #{numb} is between #{min_value} and #{lim[i+1]}"
        break
      end
    }
  end
  puts
}
```

Outputs:

```
Put a number between 0 to 100: -3
You can't enter a negative number!
[case] You can't enter a negative number!
[limit list] You can't enter a negative number!

Put a number between 0 to 100: 0
0 is between 0 and 50
[case] 0 is between 0 and 50
[limit list] 0 is between 0 and 50

Put a number between 0 to 100: 42
42 is between 0 and 50
[case] 42 is between 0 and 50
[limit list] 42 is between 0 and 50

Put a number between 0 to 100: 50
50 is between 0 and 50
[case] 50 is between 0 and 50
[limit list] 50 is between 0 and 50

Put a number between 0 to 100: 84
84 is between 51 and 100
[case] 84 is between 51 and 100
[limit list] 84 is between 51 and 100

Put a number between 0 to 100: 100
100 is between 51 and 100
[case] 100 is between 51 and 100
[limit list] 100 is between 51 and 100

Put a number between 0 to 100: 168
168 is above 100
[case] 168 is above 100
[limit list] 168 is above 100
```